# Select rows with same value in one column but differing value in second column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, greatest-n-per-group

I am using PL-SQL. I do have a table named objectlist. In this table, I do have serial numbers,named as changeno, and each has production dates.

I have seen that some of the serial numbers have different production dates. I want to list **the serial numbers** that have different production dates.

Lets say that the serial 1234 has two production dates in the table. So, my sql should show like

```
1234   12.01.2015   
1234   01.12.2015
```

I do not which serials have more than one production date. Kindly show me how I can find this.

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possibilities is using analytical function [count()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm) here:

```
select changeno, pdate 
  from (
    select changeno, pdate, count(1) over (partition by changeno) cnt 
      from objectlist )
  where cnt > 1 order by changeno, pdate
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6abb8/1)

If you need this in PLSQL than put this query in procedure, function or block:

```
begin 
  for c in (
    select changeno, pdate 
      from (
        select changeno, pdate, count(1) over (partition by changeno) cnt 
          from objectlist )
      where cnt > 1 order by changeno, pdate )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(lpad(c.changeno, 10)||' '||c.pdate);
  end loop;
end;
```